# Transform with Key of "scale" must be a number :{"scale:0"}

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, navigation-drawer, css-transforms

im trying animated in react native  there is problem  in  transform...transform is not geting the  variable "scale Value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the style to Animated.View.

```
<Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ scale: scaleAnimation }]}}>
```